# Upgrading Graphics Card Process

Tags: windows-xp, graphics-card, upgrade

I want to make sure I do this right and do not have issue. I just purchased a video card and when it arrives I should:

1. Uninstall old video card drivers completely.
2. Physically install new video card.
3. Install New Drivers.

Is there any other steps or concerns I should be aware of before I start this process?

(I am running Windows XP (SP3) if that makes a difference.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are upgrading to a graphics card by the same manufacturer (Ati/Nvidia) then you can skip the first step you listed but otherwise what you listed is fine. In the past I have even skipped the first step when moving from Ati to Nvidia and it wouldn't do any damage, but it is usually best to remove the old driver.

When fitting the new card make sure that the power connector (if needed) is connected, otherwise you are good to go.

Comment: Thanks for the information, I am going from NVIDIA to ATI so I will uninstall the old drivers.